# Unzip file downloaded from internet

Tags: flutter, dart, archive

I'm downloading the zip file from the URL and unzipping it in my flutter app using [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) package.. But, I'm getting OS Error 21. I have attached a [image]screenshot of my IDE. Don't know how to solve it. Could anyone please help me out with this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your **unzipPath** is directory and you are trying to extract file.

You should check that unzipPath.path returns file or directory and then trying to extract.

Comment: As per the documentation of archive plugin extractFileToDisk take 2 parameters zip file path and output file path. In, my case unzipPath.path is returning file path.